# Making higher order components observers - Mobx React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have an application with three main components. Form allows users to select items, Preview shows those items, AppStore is a Mobx store. The button seems to work fine, adding items to the store but the Preview component isn't re-rendering in response to changes. I think this might be because I'm using a higher order component for my drag and drop feature. Does anyone know anything about getting these to work with Mobx?

The project can be found here (the only buttons I've linked up at the moment are 'Banner Image' which adds an item and 'Remove' which should remove it): https://codesandbox.io/s/vnooqvn8yy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `SortableList` needs to be passed a regular javascript array, not an observable array.

```
<SortableList items={AppStore.currentBlocks.slice()} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
```

From the mobx docs:

> ...whenever you need to pass an observable array to an external library, it is a good idea to create a shallow copy before passing it to other libraries or built-in functions (which is good practice anyway) by using **array.slice()**